# Парсинг HTML страницы. Unicode в UTF-8

Tags: html, python, python-2.x, utf-8, unicode

При парсинге страницы с помощью requests весь текст имеет следующий вид: \u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440

Пробовал использовать функцию decode('utf-8'), не помогло

Что нужно использовать, чтобы преобразовать данную строку в обычный текст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте  так:

```
"\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0440".decode("unicode-escape")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пришлось перейти в Python3, а там пишет: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode', попробовал просто вывести, текст все равно в юникоде

Comment: @Mostalk в python 3 все строки юникод, дополнительное преобразование не требуется, unicode-escape последовательности декодируются не явно средствами самого python.

Comment: Тогда как сделать строку читабельной,  если .decode("unicode-escape") не работает?

Comment: `decode` не работает потому что его нет у `str` обектов. работа со строками в python 2 и 3 отличается. Задайте отдельный вопрос.